# Best practices for designing an image album with tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm developing a serverless application for storing and searching images stored in S3. The infos about images will be stored in DynamoDB like that :

- imageID
- imageName
- imageSize
- createdAt

Now i want also to add tags (keywords) to each image, so users can filter / search images based on that tags.

My question is what's the best practice to design this Database ? Should i use 2 seperate tables : 1 for images and the other for image_tags ?

TABLE 1 :

- imageID
- imageName
- imageSize
- createdAt

TABLE 2:

- imageID
- imageTag

Or put all data in ONE table with a primary key (imageID & ImageTag) :

TABLE:

- imageID
- imageTag
- imageName
- imageSize
- createdAt

So for example if an image have a 5 tags i will have 5 entries in the table.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would put it in a different table. Basically, if you want to change every tag (e.g. add a T:<tag> for some reason) your computer/server will have to fetch less data. But on a small scale, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Typically a system like this would not only be able to quickly retrieve the tags associated with a given image ID, but also quickly retrieve the images associated with a given tag. So, perhaps an adjacency list: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong.

What you should do is add list of tags for each picture and when querying use **conditions** and especially `CONTAINS`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html):

> CONTAINS : Checks for a subsequence, or value in a set.